# An Array of Boolean executed, but the index is outside of the array region

Tags: arrays, vb.net, boolean

here I have encountered a problem, and I can't really solve it. I have created an array of Boolean, but when I execute my command in a For Each Next loop, it says that the index is outside of the array range. Below I will provide a brief summary of my code.

```
'This subroutine reads each line of the .txt file, each line contains a String
Sub openFile (ByRef list1() As String, ByVal FileName As String) 
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
        ' Open file.txt with the Using statement.
        Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FileName)
            Try
                ' Store contents in this String.
                Dim line As String
                ' Read first line.
                line = r.ReadLine()
                ' Loop over each line in file, While list is Not Nothing.
                Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
                    ' Add this line to list.
                    list1(i) = line
                    line = r.ReadLine()
                    i = i + 1
                Loop
            Catch E As System.Exception
                MessageBox.Show(E.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub

Sub Main()

'The list contains only 60 lines
Dim list(59) As String
Dim myDocs As String
myDocs = "C:\Location I have saved on my desktop"
Dim inputFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(myDocs, "names_of_sketches.txt")
openFile(list, inputFile)

'The Strings written in the .txt file is exactly the same as this list of string
Dim profile_names As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String) From
{
   1_2
   1_3
   .
   .
   .
   15_16
}

Dim A() As Boolean = {False, False, False, ..., False} '60 Falses are written here

'What this for loop does is : if the .txt file contains the name in the list of strings, then make the array of Boolean True, if not then that Boolean element stays False

        For Each f As String In list

            Dim index As Integer = profile_names.IndexOf(f)

            A(index)  =  True

        Next

For example, let's say the contents in the .txt file is like this :
 1_2
 1_3
 1_5
 1_7
 .
 .
 .

Then the array of Boolean should become :
{True, True, False, True, False, True...}
```

I don't know what exactly is the problem here, I tried to set the array of Boolean like the following :

But the computer said that this is an invalid expression

Kindly ask for help in this
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `openFile` method should be a Function instead of passing `list1` as a ByRef variable. Not only that, but it can be greatly simplified. Take a look at this example:

```vb
Private Function ReadFileLines(filename As String) As String()
    If (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(filename)) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(filename))
    End If
    If (Not IO.File.Exists(filename)) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException($"The file does not exist at: {filename}")
    End If

    Return IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
End Function
```

Then to use it, you would do:

```vb
Dim myDocs = "C:\Location I have saved on my desktop"
Dim list = ReadFileLines(myDocs)
```

What I suspect is happening is that you have declared your `list1` as a fixed length of 60 items but when your file contains more than 60 lines.

Comment: Hello, no it is impossible to have more than 60 lines. Each line contains a name of an object in a model. And in this model there are a total of 60 objects

Comment: Sorry I forgot to provide the information. So, basically there are two errors when I ran it. The first one is `Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(filename))` The software which I am using doesn't recognize the command `NameOf` Also it says that the statement `Throw New ArgumentException($"The file does not exist at: {filename}")` has an invalid symbol. Maybe `$` is extra?

Comment: @JerryChen You are using a version of Visual Basic that does not support NameOf and String interpolation. `NameOf(filename)` can be replaced with `"filename"` where as the String interpolation can be replaced with `"The file does not exist at: " & filename`

Comment: I have modified it, and now it is functioning correctly, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Removed the hard coded 'magic number' (60) and made a few other changes.  See if it helps.

```
'This subroutine reads each line of the .txt file, each line contains a String
Sub openFile(AList As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String),
              FileName As String)
    ' Open file.txt with the Using statement.
    Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FileName)
        Try
            ' Store contents in this String.
            Dim line As String
            ' Read first line.
            line = r.ReadLine()
            ' Loop over each line in file, While line is Not Nothing.
            Do While line IsNot Nothing
                ' Add this line to list.
                AList.Add(line)
                line = r.ReadLine()
            Loop
        Catch E As System.Exception
            MessageBox.Show(E.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim SomeList As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
    Dim myDocs As String
    myDocs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim inputFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(myDocs, "test.txt")
    openFile(SomeList, inputFile)
    'initialize Booleans
    Dim A As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Boolean)
    A = (From l In SomeList Select False).ToList

    'The Strings written in the .txt file is exactly the same as this list of string
    Dim profile_names As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)

    'What this for loop does is : if the .txt file contains the name in the list of strings, then make the array of Boolean True, if not then that Boolean element stays False

    For Each f As String In SomeList
        Dim index As Integer = profile_names.IndexOf(f)
        If index >= 0 Then
            A(index) = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried running your version of the code. But several errors has occurred. The first one is, “The type ‘List’ is not defined” in ‘ Sub openFile(list1 As List(Of String), FileName As String)’ And for this statement ‘ Dim list As New List(Of String)’ it says that arrays cannot be declared with New

Comment: @JerryChen - I edited the code above.  Try again.  For some reason you don't have a reference to System.Collections.Generic in your project.

Comment: I have tried the new version of yours, but there exists three errors. The first one is this statement `AList.Add(line)`, the computer says that it is not a member of `System.Array` The second error is `Dim SomeList As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)` and `openFile(SomeList, inputFile)` The computer says that the value from type "System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)" cannot be converted in "1 dimensional Array from System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)"

Comment: And the last error is `A = (From l In SomeList Select False).ToList` It says "an expression from type "System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String) cannot be requested. And it wants me to make sure that I didn't lack any assembly referral and/or Namespaceimport for the LINQ-provider.

Comment: @JerryChen - It worked without error on my computer so I can only guess that it wasn't copied correctly(entirely).

Comment: Yes you're right, I just discovered that the first two errors weren't copied correctly. I've corrected it and it's now alright. But for the last error, which is this statement `A = (From l In SomeList Select False).ToList`, it shows the same error again, I'm not sure what is the LINQ-provider, and I'm not sure what does this statement lack. Also I'd like to ask, what is `l` in this statement? I didn't declare anything which is `l`, maybe this could be the problem

Comment: @JerryChen - do you have System.Linq in your references.  If not try adding or checking it in imported namespaces.

Comment: I have just checked, the software I am using doesn't support System.Linq.  But I have solved the problem, thank you